BUG: When window.devicePixelRatio is not an integer (e.g., 1.25), the styles of Ext JS components may render incorrectly
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio
On desktop devices, the devicePixel ratio gives us the level of zoom that the user specified using ctrl +/- and or by selecting a zoom level from the menu.
When window.devicePixelRatio is not an integer (e.g., 1.25), the styles of some Ext JS components may render incorrectly.
Demo:
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
    ]
});
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Styles have errors when the page non-integer scaling',
    columnLines: true,
    store: store,
    features: [{
      ftype: 'summary',
      dock: 'bottom',
    }],
    columns: [
        { xtype: 'rownumberer', width: 30, summaryType: 'count' },
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', width: 100, locked: true },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', width: 150 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', width: 120 }
    ],
    height: 200,
    layout: 'fit',
    fullscreen: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Online editor:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3qtb

Zoom 125% (the bug appears)

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3qtb

This is not the place to report extjs bugs - I would recommend reporting them to the developer of extjs

Sencha Forums have modernized & moved to StackOverflow!   https://forum.sencha.com/forum/

The problem appears on locked grids.
A starting point to solve this is this CSS
.x-grid-scroll-container,
.x-grid-item,
.x-grid-view {
    background: transparent!important;
}

.x-grid-scrollbar-clipper {
    border: 0 none!important;
}

Sencha currently adds the border to different items, so that (best case) it works.
But in some scenarios it does not work and the grid-view overlays the main border, while the calculation for the right grid is off 1 px.
Test my settings and try to find out what works for you.
You might want to go with the border-left on the .x-grid-scrollbar-clipper, but then you have to remove the border-right on other items.
Hope that helps. For your testing I added the css to your fiddle. Just remove the app.css to get back to the problematic part.

Thank you. It works for the locked borders, but the selected row background color dispeared

Right, this was just meant to show you, why there is a problem and how to fix it. But you are right, the background is set to transparent to show the border beneath. You might want to experiment with overflow or a width of 99%.
